# what do vulkan memory semantic flags like gl_SemanticsRelaxed, gl_SemanticsRelease, and gl_SemanticsAcquire do in Vulkan GLSL?

Tags: gpu, glsl, atomic, gpgpu, vulkan

I'm trying to figure how the atomic store functions in the following code work, they rely on `GL_KHR_memory_scope_semantics`.

```
 uint exclusive_prefix = 0;
    if (local_ix == 31) {
        atomicStore(work_buf[my_tile * 4 + 2], total, gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelaxed);
        uint flag = FLAG_AGGREGATE_READY;
        if (my_tile == 0) {
            atomicStore(work_buf[my_tile * 4 + 3], total, gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelaxed);
            flag = FLAG_PREFIX_READY;
        }
        atomicStore(work_buf[my_tile * 4 + 1], flag, gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelease);
        if (my_tile != 0) {
            // step 4: decoupled lookback
            uint look_back_ix = my_tile - 1;
            while (true) {
                flag = atomicLoad(work_buf[look_back_ix * 4 + 1], gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsAcquire);
                if (flag == FLAG_PREFIX_READY) {
                    uint their_prefix = atomicLoad(work_buf[look_back_ix * 4 + 3], gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelaxed);
                    exclusive_prefix = their_prefix + exclusive_prefix;
                    break;
                } else if (flag == FLAG_AGGREGATE_READY) {
                    uint their_agg = atomicLoad(work_buf[look_back_ix * 4 + 2], gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelaxed);
                    exclusive_prefix = their_agg + exclusive_prefix;
                    look_back_ix--;
                }
                // else spin
            }

            // step 5: compute inclusive prefix
            uint inclusive_prefix = exclusive_prefix + total;
            shared_prefix = exclusive_prefix;
            atomicStore(work_buf[my_tile * 4 + 3], inclusive_prefix, gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelaxed);
            flag = FLAG_PREFIX_READY;
            atomicStore(work_buf[my_tile * 4 + 1], flag, gl_ScopeDevice, gl_StorageSemanticsBuffer, gl_SemanticsRelease);
        }
    }
```

is actually trying to accomplish.  But I can't find a single mention of what, for example, `gl_SemanticsRelaxed` even means.  The closest I can find is in the [`GL_KHR_memory_scope_semantics`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_memory_scope_semantics.txt) spec says, but it only mentions even the word "relaxed" once, and that's just to state `gl_SemanticsRelaxed`  exists.

In fact, the specification paper only seems to indirectly describe what `gl_SemanticsRelease` and `gl_SemanticsAcquire` *might* do, and completely ignore the 5 other memory semantic types.

```
 * "Release/Acquire semantics" are used to guarantee ordering between
    an atomic or barrier and other memory operations that occur before
    or after it in program order, as observed by other invocations.
```

Where this is the list of apparent semantic types:

```
        const int gl_SemanticsRelaxed         = 0x0;
        const int gl_SemanticsAcquire         = 0x2;
        const int gl_SemanticsRelease         = 0x4;
        const int gl_SemanticsAcquireRelease  = 0x8;
        const int gl_SemanticsMakeAvailable   = 0x2000;
        const int gl_SemanticsMakeVisible     = 0x4000;
        const int gl_SemanticsVolatile        = 0x8000;
```

At best I can *guess* what it means, but it doesn't make sense in context.  I assumed relaxed meant you could rearrange the atomics up until an acquire and not care, but then they release before an acquire and that just doesn't make sense to me.

These atomics are basically polling other workgroups if they are finished with their work in a prefix sum routine, full code here: https://github.com/linebender/piet-gpu/blob/prefix/piet-gpu-hal/examples/shader/prefix.comp  paper which describes algorithm here: https://research.nvidia.com/publication/single-pass-parallel-prefix-scan-decoupled-look-back

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-model-memory-semantics and https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#_a_id_memory_semantics__id_a_memory_semantics_lt_id_gt seem to provide some documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification you linked to seems pretty clear:

> gl_StorageSemantics* and gl_Semantics* values should be bitwise ORed together to generate the SPIR-V Semantics enums

And it also specifies how the GL atomic functions map to [SPIR-V atomic operations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#_a_id_atomic_a_atomic_instructions). So the answers you seek are in [the SPIR-V specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#Memory_Semantics_-id-). And the deep details are defined by the Vulkan memory model, [appendix B of the Vulkan specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap43.html#memory-model).